# Select .env file based on the patch version in React Native

Tags: xcode, react-native, environment-variables

We have defined our xcode version like 1.0.0-Dev and 1.0.0-Prod.

Is their a way to select the env variables based on the Patch. If version with patch is 1.0.0-Dev select .env.dev variables. If version with patch is 1.0.0-Prod, than select .env.prod variables.

I do not want to create multiple schemes for a reason.

Thankyou!